# Extract nested properties from an array of objects

Tags: jq

I have the following JSON file :

```
{
  "filter": [
    {
      "id": "id_1",
      "criteria": {
        "from": "mail@domain1.com",
        "subject": "subject_1"
      },
      "action": {
        "addLabelIds": [
          "Label_id_1"
        ],
        "removeLabelIds": [
          "INBOX",
          "SPAM"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "id_2",
      "criteria": {
        "from": "mail@domain2.com",
        "subject": "subject_1"
      },
      "action": {
        "addLabelIds": [
          "Label_id_2"
        ],
        "removeLabelIds": [
          "INBOX",
          "SPAM"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to extract emails values : **mail@domain1.com** and **mail@domain2.com**

I have tried this command:

```
jq --raw-output '.filter[] | select(.criteria.from | test("mail"; "i")) | .id'
```

But does not work, I get this error :

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1206): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is
not a string exit status 5
```

Another point : how to display the value of "id" key, where "from" key value = mail@domain1.com ?

So in my file id = id_1

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: What are the patterns for matching an email? When there's a match do you only want to keep the email or do you want to keep the whole object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to extract the emails from `.criteria.from` then this filter is enough as far as I can tell:

```
jq --raw-output '.filter[].criteria.from' file.json
```

If some objects don't have a criteria object then you can filter out nulls with:

```
jq --raw-output '.filter[].criteria.from | select(. != null)' file.json
```

If you want to keep the emails equal to `"mail@domain1.com"`:

```
jq --raw-output '.filter[].criteria.from | select(. == "mail@domain1.com")' file.json
```

If you want to keep the emails that start with `"mail@"`:

```
jq --raw-output '.filter[].criteria.from | select(. != null) | select(startswith("mail@"))' file.json
```

Comment: ok thanks. and I need to extract a specific email value like : mail@domain1.com

Comment: @TooNetCreation I don't understand; if you have that value already what else do you need to extract? Are you looking to extract emails that match a specific pattern?

Comment: yes I need to extract email that match a specific pattern. ex : how to mail@domain1.com from the JSON ?

Comment: I have updated post 1 with one more question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to extract emails values

There is a wide spectrum of possible answers, with these
amongst the least specific with respect to where in the JSON the email addresses occur:

```
.. | objects | .from | select(type=="string")
```

```
.. | strings | select(test("@([a-z0-9]+[.])+[a-z]+$"))
```

Comment: in reality Idon't want to display the email, I only want to display ID value for a specific email typed

Comment: update : problem was on my json file, this command works : .filter[] | select(.criteria.from | test("string"; "i")) | .id